Find the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ rank of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.
Given a group $G$ we define its $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ rank, denoted as $\mathrm{rk}_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}(G)$ to be the maximum $n$ such that $\left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)^n\hookrightarrow G$.
I would like to prove that $\mathrm{rk}_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}(\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}))=n$.
Consider the matrix $E_i=(e_{k,j}^i)\in\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ given by $e_{k,j}^i=0$ if $k\neq j$, $e_{k,k}^i=1$ if $k\neq i$ and $e_{i,i}^i=-1$. This matrix is an involution, i.e. $E_i^2=I_n$, and $\langle E_1,\cdots,E_n\rangle\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$, so  $\mathrm{rk}_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}(\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}))\geq n$.
But I don't know how to prove that $\mathrm{rk}_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}(\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}))\leq n$, i.e. there is no embedding $\left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)^{n+1}\hookrightarrow \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.
Thanks for your help.

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group. A homomorphism $\rho: A \to \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is injective if and only if $\iota\circ \rho: A \to \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is injective (where $\iota: \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the natural inclusion).
So look w.l.o.g. on injective homomorphisms $\rho: A \to \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. $\rho$ is a representation of $A$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Since $A$ is finite, $\rho$ is completely reducible, and since $A$ is abelian, every irreducible representation is one-dimensional. So, $\rho = \rho_1\oplus \dots \oplus \rho_n$ with $\rho_i: A \to \text{GL}(V_i)$ and $\mathbb{C}^n = V_1 \oplus \dots \oplus V_n$ and $\dim V_i = 1$. Therefore there are homomorphisms $\lambda_i: A \to \mathbb{C}^*$ and a matrix $S \in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ with
$$\rho(a) = S \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1(a) & & \\ &\ddots & \\ & & \lambda_n(a) \end{pmatrix}S^{-1}$$
Set now $A = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^m$. In $A$ every element has order $\leq 2$, so $\text{Im}(\lambda_i) \subseteq \{\pm1\}$ for all $i = 1,\dots,n$ (since only $\pm 1$ have order $\leq 2$ in $\mathbb{C}^*$). Therefore $\# \rho(A) \leq \# \{\pm 1\}^n = 2^n$. Thus if $\rho$ is injective it must be $2^m =\# A \leq \# \rho(A) \leq 2^n$, which is equivalent to $m \leq n$.

Let $\Gamma < \text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ be a subgroup with $\Gamma \approx (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)^k$.
In this situation, you can regard $\Gamma$ as a matrix group over $\mathbb C$, and now you can apply the Lie-Kolchin theorem to conclude that, after a change of basis of $\mathbb C$, the matrices of $\Gamma$ are all upper triangular $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb C$. (See the comments: Using the Lie Kolchin theorem seems to be overkill)
Since each matrix has finite order, each matrix is diagonalizable.
Since the square of each matrix is the identity, every diagonal entry is $\pm 1$.
So now you have embedded $\Gamma$ into $(\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)^n$, hence $k \le n$.

I don't think you need to use Lie-Kolchin. All matrices in $\Gamma$ commute with each other and are diagonalisable over $\mathbf C$. Now take a simultaneous diagonalisation.

I agree with @Tzimmo that you can get by with the two elementary facts (i) involutions are diagonalisable in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$; (ii) commuting operators are simultaneously diagonalisable. (but I +1 the answer)

Thanks, I appended a reference to these comments.
